# What is the correct PCI-X riser card for the IBM 3650 M2?

Tags: ibm, hardware

I bought a IBM 3650 M2, and a riser card for that, Part Number 46M1074. This is the PCI-X riser card. Now, my admin team says that the card isn't fitting?? I'm not personally at the scene, but I've checked on the net, and this DOES seem to be the correct card for this server.  Am I totally wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Given this part is a PCI-X riser card and can support both PCI and PCI-X physically and electrically I suspect you really needed a PCI-e riser card. Your server actually ships with two low-profile PCI-e (x8 physically, x4 electrically) slots on the system board a two slot full-height PCIe riser card (x8 both physically and electrically) that has probably been replaced by this PCI-X riser card. If you can find this PCI-e riser card then you should just be able to replace it with the PCI-X one that's been fitted. If you can't fing it then you need to buy either it's exact replacement (IBM Part Number 46M1072) or alternatively the single slot PCI-e x16 riser card (IBM Part Number 46M1073) if that's what you need. Best of luck.

Comment: I haven't looked up this server at all, but I know on new HP servers they have the 8 or 16x PCIe slots, and the PCI-X riser cards have a bridge chip on them, so they plug into the PCIe slot. Could be the same case here.

Comment: and chopper once again demonstrates his awesome in depth hardware knowledge :)

Comment: I can't find the original IBM part anywhere - can you recommend a working alternative from other vendors?

Comment: Nope, this was a LOOOONG time ago, try not to use such old hardware, remember this site if for professional sysadmins working in a professional supportable environment as it states when you sign up for the site.